# How to ignore specific characters in string

Tags: python

I have these variables

`m1 = 'ZZZZZ'`

`m2 = 'Z___Z'`

`m3 = 'ZZZZZ'`

that represent a maze. When I print these strings out, I want it to ignore the underscores and replace them with spaces. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()`:

For example,

```py
'Z___Z'.replace('_', ' ')
```

will output:

```py
Z   Z
```